# create a synchronous http.get()

Tags: http, typescript, angular

Im trying to handle a login via promises and http.get but i fail so hard I get following error :

> Object doesn't support property or method 'toPromise'

My code is  :

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/login/', {
  headers: authHeader
}).map((response) => {
  return response.json()
}).toPromise(null);
```

ive got it from :

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-there-and-back-again/blob/master/src/app/core/character.service.ts

UPDATE :

JohnPapa updated his project my friends

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-there-and-back-again/blob/master/app/core/character.service.ts

Comment: Are you trying to return a promise? If not, get rid of the toPromise(null)

Comment: yes this is my return object  Promise<Benutzer[]>

Comment: Synchronous XHR on the UI thread is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder if you actually use promise since the HTTP support of Angular relies on Observables.

To get the response, you simply need to return the observable for your call:

```
getSomething() {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/login/', {
    headers: authHeader
  }).map((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
}
```

When calling the method, you can then register callbacks using the `subscribe` method:

```
getSomething().subscribe(
  data => handleData(data),
  err => reject(err));
```

If you really want to use promises (with the `toPromise` method), you should import this:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

See this issue for more details: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5632#issuecomment-167026172.

Otherwise, FYI calls aren't synchronous regarding HTTP in browsers...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Which function can't found? Did you use the import? I haven't this error on my side... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can use a TypeScript wrapper for **sync-request** library.

This TypeScript strongly-typed, fluent wrapper library is **ts-sync-request**.

[**ts-sync-request on npm**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-sync-request)

With this library, you can make sync http calls like below:

**Your TypeScript classes**:

```
class Request
{
    Email: string;
}

class Response
{
    isValid: boolean;
}
```

**Install package in project**:

```
 npm i ts-sync-request
```

Then

```
import { SyncRequestClient } from 'ts-sync-request/dist'
```

**GET**:

```
    let email = "jdoe@xyz.com";
    let url = "http://localhost:59039/api/Movies/validateEmail/" + email;

    var response = new SyncRequestClient()
                                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NDc2OTg1MzgsIm5iZiI6MTU0NzY5NDIxOCwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvbmFtZSI6InN0cmluZyIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vd3MvMjAwOC8wNi9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvcm9sZSI6InN0cmluZyIsIkRPQiI6IjEvMTcvMjAxOSIsImlzcyI6InlvdXIgYXBwIiwiYXVkIjoidGhlIGNsaWVudCBvZiB5b3VyIGFwcCJ9.qxFdcdAVKG2Idcsk_tftnkkyB2vsaQx5py1KSMy3fT4")
                            .get<Response>(url);
```

**POST**:

```
    let url = "http://localhost:59039/api/Movies/validateEmailPost";
    let request = new Request();
    request.Email = "jdoe@xyz.com";

    var response = new SyncRequestClient()
                                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NDc2OTg1MzgsIm5iZiI6MTU0NzY5NDIxOCwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvbmFtZSI6InN0cmluZyIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vd3MvMjAwOC8wNi9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvcm9sZSI6InN0cmluZyIsIkRPQiI6IjEvMTcvMjAxOSIsImlzcyI6InlvdXIgYXBwIiwiYXVkIjoidGhlIGNsaWVudCBvZiB5b3VyIGFwcCJ9.qxFdcdAVKG2Idcsk_tftnkkyB2vsaQx5py1KSMy3fT4")
                            .post<Request, Response>(url, request);
```

Hope this helps.